# What is cpumask in mm_struct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture

I am reading TLB shootdown code in linux kernel and I saw that shootdown ipi's were sent only to cpu's set in `cpu_vm_mask_var` in the corresponding `mm_struct` but I couldn't find where the `cpu_vm_mask_var` is being updated.

So the questions are:

1. What does `cpu_vm_mask_var` field in `mm_struct` represent?
2. Where is it being updated?

I think in shootdown case `cpu_vm_mask_var` should say how many CPU's contains present processes TLB entries but is that what exactly maintained by `cpu_vm_mask_var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory descriptor of each process has a bit mask called `cpu_vm_mask_var` and it is typically used when the process is executing on at least one processor. When a process is scheduled to run on a processor, the corresponding bit of the bit mask is set. Similarly, when the scheduler decides to run something else on the processor, the corresponding but is reset. The field `cpu_vm_mask_var` is modified in three situations:

- When the memory descriptor changes by calling [switch_mm](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/arch/um/include/asm/mmu_context.h#L61). In this case, the bit that corresponds to the current processor is cleared for the previous process and is set for the next process.
- When a new processor is added to the system, the [clear_tasks_mm_cpumask](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/kernel/cpu.c#L764) function gets called, which resets the bit that corresponds to the new processor.
- `cpu_vm_mask_var` is used to support the lazy TLB switching mechanism. If the scheduler decides to run a kernel thread, it will turn on lazy TLB mode by calling [enter_lazy_tlb](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/arch/x86/mm/tlb.c#L346). However, in this case, there is no need to invalidate a TLB entry that refers to a user-mode paging structure entry because kernel threads don't access user mode entries. So performance can be improved by disabling TLB shootdowns requests for the processor on which the kernel thread is running and delay the invalidation until switching back to the process that may use the invalidated entries. When a processor that is running a kernel thread receives for the first time an inter-processor interrupt to invalidate one or more TLB entries, the [switch_mm_irqs_off](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.14/source/arch/x86/mm/tlb.c#L183) function gets called. This function (in this particular case) will reset the bit that corresponds to the current processor in the bit mask so that it no longer receives any IPIs regarding flushing TLB user-mode entries. When the processor switches to a process that has a different memory descriptor, the write to CR3 will flush all the non-global TLB entries. Otherwise, when the processor switches back to the same process, it knows that one or more has become invalid and so it also flushes all non-global TLB entries. `cpu_vm_mask_var` is modified in `switch_mm_irqs_off`. Note that flushing kernel-mode TLB entries don't use this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for excellent answer. Is the lazy TLB optimization to reduce TLB flush overhead while switching to kernel thread and switching back to the same user process with out any invalidations in between?

Comment: @mathworker TLB shootdowns of kernel-mode entries (global entries) can still occur. Only shootdowns of user-mode entries are delayed until switching the context to some user thread. Yes, this is a performance optimization. When a processor modifies some paging structure entry, it sends a shootdown IPI to all processors whose corresponding bit in `cpu_vm_mask_var` is set. So if the bit was not set, the IPI will not be sent.

Comment: you mentioned writing to CR3 will flush all the non-global TLB entries, then what is the use of ASID in TLB entry? Since at any time TLB entries of only one address-space will be there in TLB.

Comment: @mathworker The move to CR3 behaves differently when ASIDs are enabled on the processors. In this case, you can pass an ASID as an operand to the instruction so that only those entries that have the same ASID are invalidated. Global entries and entries with other ASIDs are not invalidated. This is also a performance optimization. When ASIDs are disabled, writing to CR3 always invalidates all non-global TLB entries.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.